# Server returns blank pages with asp.net 3.5 on IIS6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I have a problem with site deployed on IIS6 sever. Here the problem, when I first deploy asp.net 3.5 site to server (site is relatively small with 5 pages and 5 libraries in bin), it is works as expected. But after some period of time (~1h) server returns black pages instead of expected content:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>
```

First my idea was that my site conflicts with other .net 2.0 sites that hosted in the same server, so I put my site into dedicated pool but without success. First time site works, then no. There is no errors or something like that in iis logs. And I do not use ClearError() method in my site.

I have found similar question [here (I’m getting blank pages instead of error messages using classic ASP, IIS6 and WinServer 2003 R2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243457/im-getting-blank-pages-instead-of-error-messages-using-classic-asp-iis6-and-win), but it is for classic ASP.

Also several topics at ASP.NET:

- [Blank page problem.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1423943.aspx)
- [Blank pages on deployed website](http://forums.asp.net/t/1166864.aspx)
- [blank page in IIS 7 on Server 2K8](http://forums.asp.net/p/1432022/3224449.aspx)

But this solutions also not help me. For example when I replace web.config with new one, or replace one of the required assemblies with rebuilded one, I have the same result. First time site works, then - black pages.

From what I see, I think that this is kind of configuration problem, but I completely stunned right now, because I've tried everything and now I lack any ideas, so help is very appreciated.

Comment: If  you add static html page to this site, will iis show it when asp stops working?

Comment: Also can you see any request in iis logs that point to your site when asp stops working?

Comment: Yes static html returned as expected, as well as any static content, styles, images, etc.

Comment: Is the application pool in a stopped state when the blank pages are returned?

Comment: Can see you access logs to this site when you try to get asp content? Or nothing happens and there is no information in access log?

Comment: @Kane, no application pool is working when blank pages return.
@empi, successful hits (200) to my .aspx pages stored in iis log

Comment: Make sure your windows is fully updated. I remember IIS behaving unexpectedly on Windows 2003. After update, problems are gone. Don't remember what the issue was, but could probably dig it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find the origins of the problem. However problem was solved by using Publish Project wizard. Original variant was distributed at xcopy basis with code-behind sources.

Answer (score 3):

I have just had **exactly** the same problem with IIS 7.5.

I tried uninstalling IIS multiple times, changing configuration etc., but nothing seemed to do any difference. I followed all the guides available - still nothing.

What I ended up doing, was completely removing IIS and all related files and configuration (except registry settings):

- Uninstall IIS via Add/Remove Programs > Turn Windows Features on or off
- Rebooted
- Removed the directory including all files: c:\inetpub
- Removed the folder inkluding all files: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv
- Reinstalled IIS via Add/Remove Programs > Turn Windows Features on or off

Finally it worked. Hope someone else will benefit from this :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its an issue with your browser temporary files.
I am assuming you are using Internet Explorer browser in which case try the following:

Goto Tools->Internet Options. Under 'General' tab, clear the browser history by clicking on 'delete' button.

Comment: It's not IE temp files because it occurs in FF also. A 500 status is returned, but with empty response body.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on our QA Server (with the latest changes). Everything was running 100% on the development box but not on QA. Eventually I had to overwrite my QA server with code from Production and then used Beyond Compare to transfer changes file by file and line by line. The error came from the `CSS` snippet below. I didn't find the reason why but I wrote a work around.

```
.dt-action-text {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;
    color: #333333 !important;
    margin-left: 5px !important;
}
```

This was done to override the the parent settings, but didn't work so well.

**In short:** Check your `CSS` as well, it might be the culprit.