# Problems with Publish Web giving blank page

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012, publish

I have written my first asp.net website and I'm ready to deploy. I've followed this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis) to the letter in order to test first and all seems to proceed without any hitches or errors. However, the webpage gives a blank page with nothing rendered, only

```
<html><head><style type="text/css"></style></head><body></body></html>
```

All the files seem to have deployed correctly and I can see them in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test Webpage` and if I attempt to run using `inetmgr` I get the same.

Can anyone advise what the problem(s) might be? Below are some screenshots of IIS if it helps but will post up more info if needed.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is your startup page? I believe it defaults to default.aspx. Have you put anything in that page? You can change your start page by right-clicking it in the solution explorer and selecting Set as Start Page.

Comment: My startup page is home.aspx and I have already set it as start page. Web Config also has... defaultUrl="home.aspx". I just re-tried and same result?

Comment: Check this one http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-using-aspnet-35-and-aspnet-45

Comment: You might also look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164494/server-returns-blank-pages-with-asp-net-3-5-on-iis6

It's not exactly the same, but may have a similar cause.

Also, is your publish profile setup to overwrite existing files, or delete all files when you publish? If the former, try the latter.

Comment: And one more, if you're using authentication.