# IIS 7.5 on Win7 does not show 500 errors

Tags: windows-7, hidden

I have IIS 7.5 (Win7 Pro) which I use for development and testing purposes. Since a few days ago, IIS behaves very strangely when it comes to errors.
All following examples refer to a simple asp page with just one line of code

**Scenario 1**

```
Response.Write "Hello " "World" ' Please note the missing ampersand
```

IIS Response: Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0401' Expected end of statement

**Scenario 2**

```
Respone.Write "Hello " & "World" ' Just missing s in Response
```

IIS Response: nothing (not even "Server Error" or stuff like that)

**Scenario 3**

```
Response.Write "Hello " & "World"
```

Response: Hello World

IIS is configured as follows:
[IIS | ASP | Debugging] Send Errors to Browser: true
[IIS | Error Pages | Edit Feature Settings] Error Responses: Detailed Errors

Until a few days ago I would get an error response also under Scenario 2. Now when IIS encounters any runtime error it just stops there and does nothing.

Anyone has ideas on what's going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the same drastic approach suggested in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/2295242/3442319 and I am pleased to say it works. Specifically what I did was:

- Unistalled via Control Panel --> Programs and features --> Turn Windows Features on or off  the following items: Internet Information Services, Internet Information Services Hostable Web Core, Windows Process Activation Service
- Reboot
- Remove the c:\inetpub directory completely (to this end removing Windows Process Activation Service is key)
- Reboot
- Reinstalled via Control Panel --> Programs and features --> Turn Windows Features on or off  the following items: Internet Information Services, Internet Information Services Hostable Web Core, Windows Process Activation Service
- Reboot
- Reconfigured IIS (you'll need to do this from scratch: saving and reimporting configuration will just replicate the problem)

Hope this helps anyone who should run into the same problem. Not the easiest end certainly not a painless approach. But it works.